# Referencing an array item in a function (as string) javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I created an array of strings, with the format "monthX" where is a number that increases throughout the array.

I have a function where I'm trying to reference a specific item of the array, but it keeps coming in as undefined. Here's my code:

```
function listCategories() {
    categoryList.innerHTML = ""

    for (var propertyName in categoryObject) {
        var rowHTML = "<div>"
        rowHTML += "<span class = 'category'>" + categoryObject[propertyName].name + "</span>"
        rowHTML += "<span class = '" + monthList[3] + "'><input/></span>"
        rowHTML += "</div>"
        categoryList.innerHTML += rowHTML
    }
}

//Months to load in
for (var i=0; i<24; i++) {
    monthList[i] = "month" + (i + startingMonth)
}
```

The area I'm interested in is that "monthList[3]" line. That keeps coming in as undefined, even though I console.log(monthList[3]) it correctly says "month6". Any ideas? Do I have bug in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, two questions:
WHEN do you call "listCategories()" ?
before or after you set monthList?

And, have you set the global for monthList first?

```
    //globalize monthList array to be usable in functions
var monthList;

function listCategories() {
    categoryList.innerHTML = ""

    for (var propertyName in categoryObject) {
        var rowHTML = "<div>"
        rowHTML += "<span class = 'category'>" + categoryObject[propertyName].name + "</span>"
        rowHTML += "<span class = '" + monthList[3] + "'><input/></span>"
        rowHTML += "</div>"
        categoryList.innerHTML += rowHTML
    }
}

//Months to load in
for (var i=0; i<24; i++) {
    monthList[i] = "month" + (i + startingMonth)
}

//do NOT CALL listCategories prior this line!!
```

That should do

Comment: There is still a problem with this.  You have declared `monthList` but you have not defined it as an array. This will result in an error like, "TypeError: can't convert undefined to object"

Comment: Thank you, itsid!

You gave me the answer when you said: //do NOT CALL listCategories prior to this line!!

Comment: @JAAulde, uups you're right... sorry I missed that, I had too much php that day where you can put objects in formerly boolean vars just like that.

Answer (score 0):

In the code you show us, you never declare `monthList` or define it as an array.

```
function listCategories() {
    categoryList.innerHTML = ""

    for (var propertyName in categoryObject) {
        var rowHTML = "<div>"
        rowHTML += "<span class = 'category'>" + categoryObject[propertyName].name + "</span>"
        rowHTML += "<span class = '" + monthList[3] + "'><input/></span>"
        rowHTML += "</div>"
        categoryList.innerHTML += rowHTML
    }
}

var monthList = [],
    startingMonth = 1;

//Months to load in
for (var i=0; i<24; i++) {
    monthList[i] = "month" + (i + startingMonth)
}
```

Notice the additional lines I added after the function definition, but before the loop.